# re.sub not converting apostrophes to spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

**Description**

I'm trying to get `re.sub()` to replace all apostrophes and and commas to a space.

**Code**

```
content = "he knew that the people were right. I'm I'm I'm I'm I'm"
content = re.sub("^[^*$<,>?!']*$", ' ', content)

OUTPUT:
"he knew that the people were right. I'm I'm I'm I'm I'm"
```

This returns the same string and does not convert anything to spaces.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you arrived at your substitution code, but I'm afraid it's way off-base. As written, it says "Only if the string contains no asterisks, dollar signs, less-than signs, commas, greater-than signs, question marks, exclamation points or apostrophes, replace the whole thing with a single space."

If you want to replace apostrophes and commas with spaces, the regex is somewhat simpler:

```
>>> content = "he knew that the people were right. I'm I'm I'm I'm I'm"
>>> re.sub(r"[,']", ' ', content)
'he knew that the people were right. I m I m I m I m I m'
```

The regex is simply this:

```
[,']  matches either a comma or an apostrophe
```

In general, the regex construct `[...]`, called a *character class*, matches a single character that is any of the ones contained between the brackets. There are some exceptions, one of which is used in your original code: if the very first character after the `[` is a caret (`^`), that negates the character class so it matches any single character that's *not* one of the remaining ones in the brackets.

So your original regex breaks down like this:

```
^ match only at the start of the string
[^...] match anything EXCEPT these characters
* 0 or more times
$ match only at the end of the string
```

The result is that the regex is matched against the entire string (because of the ^ and $), and the match succeeds only if that string contains none of those characters inside the brackets after the caret. If it does succeed, since it matches the whole string, the whole string is replaced - which means even if your original `re.sub` did match the string, it would just return a single space, no matter what the input string was.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you only want to replace single characters,  don't match whole string. `^` matches start of string `.*` matches to end of string
2. always escape special characters
   your solution then becomes (inserted a comma to show it gets replaced as well)

```
content = "he knew that(,) the people were right. I'm I'm I'm I'm I'm"
re.sub("[\',\,]", ' ', content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `.replace()` function, like so:

```
content = "he knew that the people were right. I'm I'm I'm I'm I'm"
content = content.replace("'", " ")

print(content)
```

Output is now:

```
he knew that the people were right. I m I m I m I m I m
```

Hope this helps!